# Checkout git branch with only the first few characters of a branch name

Tags: git

Is there a command I can use where I can say `git checkout branch_na*` and it would autocomplete and checkout that branch?

Comment: Negative Ghostrider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was just wondering if git support wildcards

Using it as you mention would rely on the bash (which does not know anything about branches)

So you need to rely on other means to other mean, like:

```
git checkout $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/branch_na.*|head)
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a way to use wildcards like `*` in that context. However, there is a [Git bash autocomplete script](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks) where you can press `<Tab>` to autocomplete partially typed branch names at the shell prompt.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that actually and I use that too. I was just wondering if git support wildcards.

Comment: That link is now dead/redirected to v2 of the book, which consequently makes me unable to find the aforementioned autocomplete script.

Comment: @Nuclear03020704: The git autocomplete script is now normally supplied with the Git package. Here is the completion scripts in the Git repo itself: https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/completion

Answer (score 2):

This will help in extracting branch name via wildcard. 
As branch also gives extra * and a space we trim those to avoid pathspec problem.

```
git checkout $(git branch --list "*branch-name-*" | tr '*' ' ')
```